# How to draw protonated benzene (horseshoe) carbocation structure with ChemDraw?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, software, notation

Is there a way to draw the aromatic "horseshoe" (forgot the official name) structure of a protonated benzene cation (arenium) with ChemDraw, and not the cation with double bonds?

[image: benzenium]

Comment: I've added an image produced with [chemfig](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) to illustrate your question — hopefully it reflects your point. If not, feel free to add your own image instead:)

Comment: It's called Arenium ion. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arenium_ion

Answer (score 5):

Draw cyclohexane. Open Drawing Elements. Select 270<sup>o</sup> circle. Orient with lasso and adjust size. Insert in cyclohexane. Add H's and +.
[image]
**ADDENDUM**: For a centered structure. Draw cyclohexane, arc and + inside each other. Select them. Go to Object>align. Select L/R centered then T/B centered. Add hydrogens. See also Comments. PS: Clearly, ChemDraw does not recognize the structure as protonated benzene. Can't have everything ;).
[image]

Comment: Interesting, this is exactly what I had in mind. What prevented me from writing an answer is that this way the charge is treated by ChemDraw as the stray one, and the entire molecule is recognized as cyclohexane if one would try to generate its name (Alt+Ctrl+N). Also, what bugs me is that vertical alignment tool doesn't work nicely for arcs, so it cannot be perfectly centered within the ring. Are you aware of any means to overcome all those issues?

Comment: CD13 or 17 cannot handle "Structure to Name". But that wasn't the question. On an Apple laptop I had no problem (CD13) with orienting the arc or reducing its size. I hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: @andselisk: About centering.. Draw ring, arc and + inside each other. Select them. Go to Object>align. Select L/R centered then T/B centered.

Comment: CD18 on Windows can generate a name, but, as I said, it's cyclohexane and is wrong. As for alignment, that's exactly what I did, but it looks like the *cut edge* is used for alignment of arcs, not the circumference, which drives my internal perfectionist nuts:) ([my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYspK.png)) But you are right, that's nitpicking and not what OP asked, and the proposed method helps drawing something that is close enough, so +1.

Comment: @andselisk: I was able to make a centered structure that now reads cyclohexane. How do you put a screen shot in comments?

Comment: I upload the image in the answer field, copy the URL, paste it in the comments normally via `[screenshot](URL)`, and discard the answer :) But that's precisely what I was talking about, CD doesn't treat this structure as arenium, which is a problem IMO. As for alignment, maybe I messed something up, I'm not a CD guru by any means (the vertical alignment on your second screenshot is also wrong — the arc is shifted to the top a bit).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91611/discussion-between-user55119-and-andselisk).

Answer (score 0):

That is a terrible way of drawing that intermediate. You should draw a cyclohexane, then right-click on the four bonds where the delocalization takes place and choose double -> tautomeric.[image: benzenium]

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE. @andselisk was asking for a way to draw the structure he provided. He did not ask for the "best" way to do it. We strive to be a kind and caring community.  " Here is an alternative way of drawing that intermediate" would have been a more civil statement. You may wish to consider an edit. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/conduct

Comment: @user55119 I didn't ask the question, Cloud Chem did:) I only added an illustration to what is commonly shown in the literature as a "horseshoe benzene". Despite the main part of the post being critics, I think it is still a valid alternative answer.

Comment: @andselisk: My mistake. I still stand by the rest of my Comment.