# Conversion of Benzene to 9-Bromo 9,10 Dihydroanthracene

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

I tried to proceed through following steps:
Step-1: [image: Step-1":]

Step 2:[image]

Step-3:[image]

Step-4:[image]

I agree with the fact that yield might not be good. But is this whole reaction possible? Am I going correct? A better method and the corrections to this method are appreciated!

Comment: Wait: how, assuming non-nuclear chemistry, do you convert Cl (step #3, 1,2-dichlorobenzene, coupling mediated by sodium) into C?

Comment: This is probably the first time I see *four* different drawing styles in one post:)

Comment: @andselisk In the longer run, I'm more concerned about (still) drawing the Thiele (?) ring in benzene's structure.  Too easy to lose track of counting the $\pi$-electrons present, not only for first time learning about either electrophilic or nucleophilic aromatic substitutions.  Even more so for e.g., naphthalenes when some drawings coalesce these individual Thiele rings across bonds into something in a shape like a toilet seat.

Comment: @andselik Haha..Some of them I had to copy paste from google while I had to make some of them on my own..didn't have any one source :P

Comment: Where do the two methylene groups come from in the step from 1,2-di-chlorobenzene to di-hydroanthracene? Step 3 looks OK

Comment: @Buttonwood I completely agree, good point about Thiele rings. I think you mean a so-called [horseshoe bond](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/111618/how-to-draw-protonated-benzene-horseshoe-carbocation-structure-with-chemdraw).

Comment: Consider the Friedel-Crafts reactions of phthalic anhydride

Comment: @Waylander I am Sorry, I have edited step-3, I took another compound "1,2 Chloromethyl benzene" I hope it is correct now!

Comment: I think you would be better off starting from two equivalents of benzyl chloride. Those can react with each other in Friedel-Crafts fashion, yielding 9,10-dihydroanthracene. Use one equivalent of NBS afterwards and you obtain your product.

Comment: @TheRelentlessNucleophile Thank you, It was helpful!

Comment: OP has shown research effort and it should not get downvoted.

Comment: @andselisk While very descriptive, the horseshoe _is not_ the form I thought about, because it lacks crossing a bond.  I made a photo for the chatroom [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57720493#57720493), as young as by about 2002.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is known as the Wurtz-Fittig reaction - [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wurtz%E2%80%93Fittig_reaction) , [JACS paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01334a044)

In this proposed reaction I think you will get a complex mixture (also known as a mess), but you may be able to find some of your desired product in it. Good luck with trying to isolate it cleanly!

If you want a straightforward preparative route then look at the F-C reaction of phthalic anhydride with benzene, the reduction of the resulting 2-benzoyl benzoic acid to 2-benzyl benzoic acid and cyclisation with polyphosphoric acid. This product can be reduced to the dihydroanthracene by Zn/HCl

Comment: Thankyou, but since I am a 11th grader, can you please help how do I carry out cyclisation process after reduction of carboxylic group?

Comment: You could try treating the resulting ortho-benzoylbenzoic acid with $\ce{SOCl2}$ and then carry out another acylation. But this process will for sure be low-yielding because of the deactivating nature of the acyl radical. Just start from benzoyl chloride. It's the easiest way to synthesize anything "anthracene-like" from a single aromatic nucleus.

Comment: @TheRelentlessNucleophile Thank you so much! :)

Comment: The reagent of choice for the cyclisation of the benzyl benzoic acid (reduction product from benzoyl benzoic acid) is polyphosphoric acid